# Send Dynamic Table as Model back to the controller

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to send a dynamic table back to the controller by using its model.
Following situation. On the view I am creating a table with javascript which allows the users to insert different values. These values are picked from pre-defined comboboxes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn_insert').on('click', function () 
            var table=document.getElementById("table_computerimport");
            var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
            var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='computername_row"+table_len+"'>"+computername+"</td><td id='uuid_row"+table_len+"'>"+"HERE UUID"+"</td><td id='collection_row"+table_len+"'>"+" HERE Collection Name"+"</td><td><input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";
    });
```

This is working fine, so that at least the table is created with n entries.

```
<div>
    <button type="button" id="btn_insert" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>

    <div >
        <table class="table" id="table_computerimport">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Hostname</th>
                    <th>MacAddress</th>
                    <th>GUID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>

 </div>
```

These entries I would like to pass back to the controller by using its model:

```
public IEnumerable<ComputerImportModel> TableComputerImport {get; set;}
@model ViewModels.ComputerImportViewModel
```

So I don’t want to loop though the list of objects and publish them in the view, I would like to create n records in one view at once and pass these back to the controller by using the model TableComputerImport.
I guess in Javascript somehow I have to say something like this: input asp-for="ComputerImport.hostname"

---

Update,
ok, I think I "solved" it. What I did is that I created an array with javascript out of the table and passed this by ajax to the controller. It was important that the array has the name attributes like the class does so that I can use this object in the constructor as a well defined object.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioed, I had to use an array which I send by AJAX to the controller. Because of the identical names in the table and in the model, everything goes its correct way:

```
var singlecomputerimport = [];
        var headers = [];
        $('#table_computerimport th').each(function(index, item) {
            headers[index] = $(item).html();
        });
        $('#table_computerimport tr').has('td').each(function() {
            var arrayItem = {};
            $('td', $(this)).each(function(index, item) {
                if(headers[index] !== undefined){
                    //console.log($(item));
                    //arrayItem[headers[index].toLowerCase()] = $(item).html();
                    arrayItem[headers[index].toLowerCase()] = $(item).attr('value');
                }
            });
            singlecomputerimport.push(arrayItem);
        });
```